# Powershell scheduled script is not running properly

Tags: powershell

I have a short Powershell script which backup desktop items to D drive

```
$now = [datetime]::now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$trigger=new-scheduledtasktrigger -daily -at("08:00am")
$action = new-scheduledtaskaction 'copy "C:\USERS\ADMIN\DESKTOP" "D:\$now" -recurse'
Register-scheduledtask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Taskname "dailybackup" -Description "Daily backup"
```

The code seems valid and scheduled is registered well in scheduler

```
Get-scheduledtask "dailybackup"
```

But the task haven`t executed once but don`t know why

anyone knows the solution?

Comment: For one thing you must make sure the destination directory exists before using `Copy-Item`

Comment: @Theo already did sir...

Comment: That doesn't show in your code though.. Where is the `New-Item ...` command?

Comment: You're never calling `powershell.exe` in your task action.

Answer (score 0):

`New-ScheduledTaskAction` executes commands in the old CMD shell by default. The command you're running doesn't error out because [COPY](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) is an ancient CMD built-in. It doesn't actually have the ability to recurse though, so it's not what you want.

To run powershell commands, the task action should execute `PowerShell.exe`, then have the powershell commands themselves added as arguments like below.

- It looks like you want to use the run time date as the folder name `$now`, so you'll need to re-calculate the date every time it runs,
- I also suggest adding `-Force` to create the target directory as needed,
- I'm using here-string formatting `@' '@` to make quotes and things simpler to handle:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument @'
  -Command Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path 'C:\USERS\ADMIN\DESKTOP' -Destination "D:\$([datetime]::Now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"
'@
```